# DBGrid with read ahead capability using ADO

Tags: delphi, ado, dbgrid

I'm working with ADO connecting to SQL Server 2005.

My TADODataSet selects 1 million records. using a TDBGrid and setting the `TADODataSet.CursorLocation` to `clUseServer` works. but the TDBGrid chokes!

How can I select 1 million records, avoid paging, and still be able to display records in the grid without fetching ALL records to the client side, letting the Grid read ahead as I scroll up and down?

SQL enterprise manager can execute a query and select 1 million records asynchronously without any problems (also MS-ACCESS).

Comment: Have you tried putting a ClientDataset inbetween? It will still eventually fetch all records, but it may browse faster once the lot is loaded.

Comment: I do not want to fetch 1 million records to the client side. ClientDataset will do just that.

Comment: It seems the [`TClientDataSet.PacketRecords`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet.PacketRecords) sounds promising for you. I've never tried it and cannot verify now, but it seems that if you set it to the visible DB grid row count and fetch data in the [`TClientDataSet.BeforeGetRecords`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.BeforeGetRecords) event then you'll get what you want. Another thing is that you will have to handle scrolling by your own (because DB grid won't know the total row count) and you will have to fetch the data manually.

Comment: @TLama: using incremental fetching with a TDBGrid doesn't need to fetch data manually. The grid doesn't know the total number of records (it happens with any dataset that doesn't fetch the whole dataset at once) then will just show the scrollbar bar in the middle - when the grid reaches the last fetched record the dataset will fetch another set of packets automatically, unless set otherwise, and the the grid will keep on working, i.e. the scroll bar will be reset to tell the user the dataset is not EOF nor BOF.

Comment: @Idsandon, as I said I've never tried that and at this time I can't. So, how the `CursorType` and `CacheSize` you've mentioned affects the fetching ? Does the `PacketRecords` affect it too ? I'm not talking about theory why to fetch so many data, let's say I have to fetch them incrementaly for some reson. I would like to know what should I setup for this automatic incremental fetching. Some code example would be the best ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TGrid is not your problem.  Your problem is TADODataset is trying to load all the records.  If you must run a query that returns so many records, you should set ExecuteOptions, try eoAsyncExecute and eoAsyncFetch.  It may also help to set CacheSize.

Answer (score 1):

- Why do you need to fetch 1M records into a grid? No human being can look at so many records. Usually is far better to reduce the number of records before loading them into a UI.
- If you have a good reason to show so many records into a grid, you'd need a dataset that **1)** doesn't load the whole recordset when opened **2)** doesn't cache previous record or it could run out of memory (under 32 bit Windows especially) far before reaching the end of the recordset if the record size is not small enough. To obtain such result beyond CursorLocation you have to set CursorType and CacheSize properly.
- You can use a TClientDataset to implement incremental fetching setting the ADO dataset CursorType to ForwardOnly and CacheSize to a suitable value. Because TClientDataset caches read records, you want to avoid the source dataset to load all of them as well. A standard DB grid needs a bidirectional cursor, thereby it won't work with an unidirectional one. With so many records the client dataset cache can exhaust memory anyway. I'd suggest to use the [Midas Speed Fix unit](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/47142) if you're using a Delphi version before 2010.
- To avoid "out of memory" errors you may need to implement some kind of pagination. Anyway, check if the behaviour of other CursorType can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) and TADTable. Its [Live Data Window](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Browsing_Table.html) mode solves your and similar issues. The benefits are:

- minimizes memory usage and allows to work with large data volumes, similar to an unidirectional dataset;
- enables bi-directional navigation, in contrast to an unidirectional dataset;
- gives always fresh data, reducing the need to refresh dataset;
- does not delay to fetch all result set records, required to perform sorting, record location, jumping to last record, etc.