# Insert DBGrid data into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, delphi, dbgrid

I have set a connection from Delphi to pgsql using ADOConnection, ADOQuery, DataSource and a DBGrid to present the results of my query. 
The database contains 2 columns of values of type *double*, of some thousands of rows, which I would like to insert into a two-dimensional array.However, as am quite new I am not sure how to insert the contents of a DBGrid into an array. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you decide which of the two `Double` type columns to store in the array? Rather than look at the `DBGrid` you would be better served looking at the `ADOQuery.FieldByName('Field1').AsDouble` property and using that to populate your array.

Comment: You never read data from (or write it to) the TDBGrid; access the underlying dataset fields instead. TDBGrid is for presentation and nothing more.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out already but the problem is I do not have the experience to know what's the best way of doing so nor is there any source available to satisfy my question. If you wanted to make calculations with fields from your database what would you do? You'd need to read them and write new fields. Using arrays could be a way of doing so but I got stuck.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question and aiming for the wrong solution. if you need to calculate something related to the DB, use DB solution instead of "multi-dimensional array". e.g. you have `SUM` function in SQL; you can use calculated/aggregated fields in your underling TDataSet; and so on...

Comment: Maybe you could tell us why you need that array and we could give you a better answer. As you pointed out yourself, you lack in experience in Delphi and may be choosing the wrong path as your solution.

Comment: I 'd like to make calculations using the data entries from my database. The best way I could think of is first transfer these values (which are about 8000 rows) to one (multidimensional) array .  For ex. If the array is M(i,j) it would be like M(1,1)*M(1,2) for i-->n. HTH

Answer (score 0):

First of all if there are thousands of rows you need to assign fields into variables before reading  to get rid of unnecessary text lookup time when using FieldByName.

I dont't have Delphi at hand but this should work or at least help you get started.

```
uses Math;

procedure ProcessArray(ADataSet: TDataSet);
var
  field1: TField;
  field2: TField;
  len: Integer;
  a: array of array[2] of double;
begin
  len := 0;
  SetLength(a, 0);
  field1 := ADataSet.FieldByName('field1');
  field2 := ADataSet.FieldByName('field2');
  ADataSet.First;
  while not ADataSet.Eof do
  begin
    Inc(len);
    if len > Length(a) then
      SetLength(a, len + Min(len, 16384));
    a[len - 1][0] := field1.Value;
    a[len - 1][1] := field2.Value;
    ADataSet.Next;
  end;
  SetLength(a, len);
  // Process the results in the a array
end;
```

What AlexSC is suggesting is to actually use TADODataSet.RecordCount property to set the size of an array initially. Please note that if TDataSet is not loaded completely from the database (uses server cursor for example), RecordCount will not necessarily contain the number of all records and the original solution above would be able to cope with this. I made a correction to it so it won't grow more than 16k items at once and the overhead will be at most 16k - 1 array entries. For information  about TDataSet "lazy loading" refer to [DBGrid with read ahead capability using ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547299/dbgrid-with-read-ahead-capability-using-ado)

Please find the code using RecordCount below:

```
procedure ProcessArray(ADataSet: TDataSet);
var
  field1: TField;
  field2: TField;
  len: Integer;
  a: array of array[2] of double;
begin
  len := 0;
  SetLength(a, ADataSet.RecordCount);
  field1 := ADataSet.FieldByName('field1');
  field2 := ADataSet.FieldByName('field2');
  ADataSet.First;
  while not ADataSet.Eof do
  begin
    a[len][0] := field1.Value;
    a[len][1] := field2.Value;
    Inc(len);
    ADataSet.Next;
  end;
  // Process the results in the a array here
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, am getting an "Identifier expected but ARRAY found" error. Probably because Array type can't be as a result in a function?...Is there any way without using a function, it may over complicate things

Comment: @Elena_K:  In any case, you should precede the ADataSet.First and follow the end of the While loop by ADataSet.DisableControls and ADataSet.EnableControls, respectively, otherwise you may have to wait ages while your DBGrid scrolls.

Comment: I just changed the function to procedure so that it can be compiled (still untested though). You may add some array processing code after the comment or just move the block of code to your function and add variables to your function's variables declaration section.

Comment: I would reconsider extending the array during the loop, specially by dubling it each time it´s needed. That will produce an exponential growth of the array. Instead, I would pass the record count (the dataset is a `TADOQuery`, so we can use its `RecordCount` property) as a parameter and set the array size only once.

Comment: @ AlexSC Ι see I will try using TADOQuery instead.How would that go though with regards to too's post. Too's way doesn't return an error now. But I'd like to see how would ADOQuery go, then see which solution is better.